# UnresolvedAddressException in Logstash+elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Logstash is not working in my system(Windows 7).I am using Logstash-1.4.0, kibana-3.0.0, Elasticsearch-1.3.0 version installed in my system.
I created `logstash.conf` file in logstash-1.4.0 (Logstash-1.4.0/logstash.conf).

```
input {
  file {
    path => “C:/apache-tomcat-7.0.62/logs/*access*”
  }
}
filter {
  date {
    match => [ “timestamp” , “dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z” ]
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch { host => “localhost:9205″}
}
```

And I run the logstash

`c:\logstash-1.4.0\bin>logstash agent -f ../logstash.conf`

Getting below Exception

```
log4j, [2015-06-09T15:24:45.342] WARN: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty: [logstash-IT-BHARADWAJ-512441] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x0ee1f960]], closing connection
java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
at sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Net.java:123)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:621)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink.connect(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:108)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:70)
etc……..
```

How to solve this problem

Comment: Can you make sure to use proper double quotes in your `logstash.conf`? `“` and `”` are not valid, they should be `"`, instead. It might be because you have edited this file in a Word processor instead of a raw file editor.

Comment: I know the documentation says that `hostname:port` is valid for the `host` parameter, but could you try dropping the port number and setting `port => 9205` instead?

Comment: @MagnusBäck I wrote port separately and template => "logstash" but this template is not created in Elasticsearch

Comment: I am getting this Exception in logstash console c:\logstash-1.4.0\bin>logstash agent -f ../logstash.conf   ←[33mUsing milestone 2 input plugin 'file'. This plugin should be stable, but if you see strange behavior, please let us know! For more information on plugin milestones, see http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.0/plugin-milestones {:level=>:warn}←[0m
 ←[33mUsing milestone 2 output plugin 'elasticsearch_http'.This plugin should be stable, but if you see strange behavior, please let us know!or more information on plugin milestones, see http://logstash.netdocs/1.4.0/plugin-milestones {:level=>:warn}

Comment: ←[0m
        RuntimeError: You must specify 'template => ...' in your elasticsearch_http output
          get_template_json at c:/logstash-1.4.0/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch_http.rb:190 register at c:/logstash-1.4.0/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch_http.rb:121 each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613
               outputworker at c:/logstash-1.4.0/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:220
              start_outputs at c:/logstash-1.4.0/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:152

Comment: One thing at a time. Has the UnresolvedAddressException problem disappeared? (`template` should be set to a valid file system path, which "logstash" isn't. See http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.0/outputs/elasticsearch#template.)

Comment: How to give path.The template is created in elasticsearch.And I tried like template => "http://10.50.7.109:9200/_template/logstah" but it no working

Answer (score 0):

You cant connect to the socket, by default elasticsearch sitting on 9200 port for http and 9300 for tcp. Try change it for 9200 first, its default case.